# Facing issue with SQL query with 3 tables

Tags: sql

I am facing issue in forming sql query.

I have 3 tables

Table 1 - Product

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      ProductId      |   ProductName    |      BrandId     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          P1         |       Abcd       |         B1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          P2         |       xyz        |         B2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Table 2 - Packet

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ProductId      |    PacketName    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          P1         |       Pac1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          P1         |       Pac2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          P2         |       Pac3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table 3 - Brand

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        BrandId      |     BrandName    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B1         |     Brand1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B2         |     Brand2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The Output I expect is as below

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      ProductId      |   ProductName    |     BrandName    |       Packets    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          P1         |       Abcd       |     Brand1       |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          P2         |        xyz       |     Brand2       |          1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I am facing the issue with query formation. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried with join and group by but somehow getting different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  p.productid,
  p.productname,
  b.brandname,
  count(*) as packets
from product p
join brand b on b.brandid = p.brandid
left join packet k on k.productid = p.productid
group by p.productid, p.productname, b.brandname
```